# Cannot call my custom Helper Class. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, helper

I'm trying to call my custom **Helper** class in **Controller** but when I call the function of my helper in Controller it gives me `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Backend\Helper\Data::getSKUU()`**getSKUU()** is my custom helper function and the code is calling the core helper class while I'm injecting my custom Helper class in the controller
`Vender\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index`

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Vender\Module\Helper\Email;
use Vender\Module\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
/**
 * 
 */
class AcceptOffer extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_model;
    protected $helper;

    function __construct(
         \Vender\Module\Model\ResourceModel\MakeAnOffer\CollectionFactory $model,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        Context $context,
        Email $email,
        \Vender\Module\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Vender\Module\Model\MakeAnOffer $mode
    )
    {
        $this->_model = $model;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_email = $email;
        $this->_helper= $helper;
        $this->_mode = $mode;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id= $this->request->getParam('id');

        $this->_mode->load($id)->addData(array('check_status'=>2));
        $this->_mode->setId($id)->save();

        $dataa = $this->_model->create()->addFieldToFilter('makeanoffer_id',$id)->getData(); 
        // print_r($dataa);exit;
         /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            try {
                // $this->_helper->setCoupon();
                $this->_helper->getSKUU();
                $this->_email->sendAdminEmail($dataa);
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('The Offer has been Accepted!');
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');

            } catch (\Exception $e) {

                // display error message
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                // go back to edit form
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');

            }
    }
}
//Not colling my custom Helper Class
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This **`$this->_helper= $helper;`** should be **`$this->helper= $helper;`** as you are declaring the `$helper` without **`'_'`**

Comment: ok so if I declare **$helper** like **$_helper** and after that I write `$this->_helper= $_helper` is it will work then???

Comment: I think so. should try first.

Comment: Its not working like that as well... it works on `$this->helper= $helper;` but its not making any sense for me can you please explain me??? like same as well I have the **Email** class as well in the helper but its works properly even I'm declaring the class like `$this->_email = $email;`

Comment: yeah the same in my answer it should work. check again my answer. I think because helper is a reserve word for Magento core helper

Comment: Yeah Yeah... I'm just telling you that your code `$this->helper= $helper;` is working but the same `$this->_helper= $_helper;` is not working.

Comment: I think because of the coding standard of Magento, the variable names should not be prefixed with "_" but the objectProperty names can be prefixed with `"_" ` but in the latest magento versions prefixing objectproperty names are not encouraged because magento 2 is using PSR2 coding standard